# How does vim parse quotes with `set`?

Tags: vim

I'm confused about how to use whitespace in a `set`. For example, let's say I want to change my font. I have many options:

```
set guifont=a\ b
```

This makes sense from `:help option-backslash`.

```
set guifont="a b"
```

I can't find any documentation for this, but it makes sense that quoting lets you handle whitespace. When you remove the quotes to get `set guifont=a b`, it doesn't work (unknown option `b`). So far so good.

```
set guifont='a b'
```

Here's where I'm confused. Why doesn't this work? `echo 'a b'` and `echo "a b"` produce identical output..

```
set guifont='a\ b'
```

And here my mind gets blown, because this sets guifont to `a b`, but if I `echo 'a\ b'` I get `a\ b`, which makes sense according to `:help expr-quote`.

In short: how do quotes interact with `set`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In vim `"` starts a comment. This means that `set guifont="a b"` is interpreted as `set guifont=`. (You can see this if you do `set guifont?` since the value returned is not `a b`)

The documentation from `:h option-backspace` shows that this is the case since you need to escape quotes to include it in the set command.

```
Similarly, the double quote character starts a comment.  To include the '"' in
the option value, use '\"' instead.  This example sets the 'titlestring'
option to 'hi "there"': >
   :set titlestring=hi\ \"there\"
```

For `set guifont='a b'`, single quotes are not a special character so they don't mean anything. Here you are passing two separate arguments to the set command. The first being `guifont='a` and the other being `b'` However `b'` doesn't make sense and you get `E518: Unknown option: b'`

Basically, the set command only takes whitespace separated arguments. Where vim comments are treated normally and stripped from the command. Quoting DOES NOT allow you to handle whitespace in the set command.

Vimscript is a language the evolved over time and the rules are not consistent.

Answer (score 1):

You can escape spaces with `:set`:

```
:set option=foo\ bar
```

or use quotes with `:let`:

```
:let &option = "foo bar"
```

For more information, you can type :

```
:h let-&
```

Comment: I'm aware of this, thanks! I'm not asking how to do it; I'm asking about the mechanism and rules around quoting behavior with set, which appears to be different from normal quoting behavior.